# ChartJS 4.3.0 handle click on Axes x

Tags: onclick, chart.js

[image]

I use ChartJS ver 4.3.0, i wonder if handle onClick() event on axes - x . I read document on  ChartJS but couldn't find solution.

Comment: To capture an event that fires outside the chart area you may use a simple plugin with `beforeCode` as described in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#event-option), third paragraph and code sample

Comment: Thank you @kikon, according to document i use afterEvent for my case,             plugins: [{
                id: 'myEventCatcher',
                afterEvent(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
                    const event = args.event;
                    if (event.type === 'click') {
                        let value = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(args.event.x); 
                        let label = chart.data.labels[value];
                    }
                }
            }]

Comment: You should post (a possibly simplified version of) your full code, either as a code snippet or a codepen or jsfiddle link, so we can fork it and work from there a full solution. Otherwise, you'll only get, if anything, just general recommendations